# Accessing 0xCxxxxxxx guest kernel pointers within qemu-system-mips

Tags: linux-kernel, mips, qemu

In my QEMU-based project (system emulation) I analyse various kernel structures of the guest Linux. To read the guest virtual memory I use `cpu_memory_rw_debug()` function.

In particular, I search `struct module` linked list in the kernel memory using some kind of heuristics.
Lest assume that the relevant part of an element in this list looks like this:

```
---------------------       ---------------------
| prev = 0xc1231234 |       | prev = 0xc5675678 |
---------------------       ---------------------
| next = 0xc1122334 |       | next = 0xc5566778 |
---------------------       ---------------------
| etc.              |       | etc.              |
---------------------       ---------------------
```

When QEMU emulates x86 or ARM, prev/next pointers can be accessed by `cpu_memory_rw_debug()` and they actually point to previous/next list elements.

However, when QEMU emulates MIPS, I observe the following strange behavior: while prev/next pointers look like a valid kernel pointers in every element in the list, I cannot access their pointees by means of `cpu_memory_rw_debug()`, because finding the corresponding physical address fails: the access permissions are ok, the virtual CPU is in kernel mode, but `tlb->map_address()` fails.

Since I can't walk through the linked list, I tried to find the elements one by one - just to see what their prev/next pointers look like - and I actually found all the elements, but all of them reside at `0xAxxxxxxx` addresses, not `0xCxxxxxxx`, as prev/next imply.

The function `r4k_map_address()`, which performs physical address lookup looks like this (only the relevant excerpt):

```
#define KSEG0_BASE 0x80000000UL
#define KSEG1_BASE 0xA0000000UL
#define KSEG2_BASE 0xC0000000UL
#define KSEG3_BASE 0xE0000000UL
//..............
if (address < (int32_t)KSEG1_BASE) {
  /* kseg0 */
  if (kernel_mode) {
    *physical = address - (int32_t)KSEG0_BASE;
    *prot = PAGE_READ | PAGE_WRITE;
  } else {
    ret = TLBRET_BADADDR;
  }
} else if (address < (int32_t)KSEG2_BASE) {
  /* kseg1 */
  if (kernel_mode) {
    *physical = address - (int32_t)KSEG1_BASE;
    *prot = PAGE_READ | PAGE_WRITE;
  } else {
    ret = TLBRET_BADADDR;
  }
} else if (address < (int32_t)KSEG3_BASE) {
    /* sseg (kseg2) */
    if (supervisor_mode || kernel_mode) {
      ret = env->tlb->map_address(env, physical, prot, real_address, rw, access_type);
    } else {
      ret = TLBRET_BADADDR;
  }
```

That is, on MIPS `0xC0000000...0xE0000000` range is mapped differently from lower kernel ranges.
If I replace the TLB access with `*physical = address - (int32_t)KSEG1_BASE` direct mapping, I get the things working, but certainly that's not the solution.

Does it look like QEMU-related issue or a MIPS-related one? I'd appreciate any idea or debugging direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bottom line is that `cpu_memory_rw_debug()` doesn't work reliably in qemu-system-mips.

The reason is that QEMU emulates MIPS software-managed TLB. With this approach, whenever virtual->physical address mapping does not exist in the TLB cache, QEMU emulates "TLB-miss" exception, which should be handled by the OS. It is OS responsibility to walk through the page directory and fill the TLB -- QEMU (just like real MIPS) won't do that.

While this approach works for the guest code, it results in inability
to read guest virtual memory using `cpu_memory_rw_debug()` - it
doesn't work reliably for [mapped segments](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dai0235c/AN235_migrating_from_mips_to_arm_files/image004.png).

As for the question why kernel structs that actually reside in KSEG2 where observed in KSEG1 - that's just because some virtual ranges of KSEG1 and KSEG2 correspond to the same physical pages.